# Which Windows SDK gets installed with Visual Studio 2015 Update 2?

Tags: winapi, sdk, visual-studio-2015

I've installed a few versions of Visual Studio 2015 and am now on Update 2.

I seem to have a number of Windows 10 SDK's installed and want to know which one was delivered with VS2015 Update 2 so I can target that? Then, when other devs in my team install Update 2, I'll know they've got that SDK installed.

This page lists some SDK's, but doesn't have an entry for VS2015 Update 2.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK

Comment: The latest version. 10586 currently. VS 2015 SKU does NOT contain Windows SDK inside, it downloads it from Internet.

Comment: It did update 10.0.10586.0, not very clear why.  The SDK installer is pretty crappy.

Comment: Hmm, I ran the VS2015 U2 installer again and chose Modify. It looks like you can independently select 10.0.10250.0 and 10.0.10586.0. But by default it looks like it would only install 10.0.10250.0, hmm, unless it's only got to that default because that's what VS2015 U1 put down, and the VS2015 U2 installer has decided not to change what you've already got.

Comment: I guess I'll just pick one and educate the rest of my team to install the right thing.